# A simple Q and A quiz that reinforces Ruby learning

Tags: beginner, ruby, quiz

I wrote a simple quiz which I am hoping to scale-up as I continue to learn about programming.

The code now stores questions and answers in separate arrays.

Please review this code to improve its efficacy.

```
questions = []
answers = []
q0 = "What is the command for a 'for' loop?"
a0 = "for"
q1 = "What is another name for a method?"
a1 = "function"
q2 = "what are the three types of loops that I know of?"
a2 = "while, for, and until"

questions.push(q0, q1, q2)
answers.push(a0, a1, a2)

question_counter = 0
index = 0

while true
  puts questions[index]
  question_counter += 1
  answer_attempt = gets.chomp.downcase
  if answer_attempt == answers[index]
    puts "Good job. Next question.."
  else
    puts "Incorrect. Next question"
  end
  index = index + 1
  if question_counter == 3
    puts "all done"
    break
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store related data in a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html)

Also, looping like you've done is very uncommon in Ruby. You'll see `Array#each` (or `Hash#each` in this case) much more common than storing an index in a var while iterating through indexes.

```
@success_msg = 'Good job. Next question..'
@incorrect_msg = 'Incorrect. Next question..'
{
  "What is the command for a 'for' loop?" => 'for',
  'What is another name for a method?' => 'function',
  'What are the three types of loops that I know of?' => 'while, for, and until'
}.each do |q, a|
  puts q
  puts(gets.chomp.downcase == a ? @success_msg : @incorrect_msg)
end
puts 'All done.'
```

Also, I'd try to make this multiple choice or something if you're really trying to use it, theres no way your response is going to match those answers exactly. Perhaps you could look for certain terms in the response, but parsing English for semantic meaning isn't very easy hehe.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is clumsy.  Both `index = index + 1` and `if question_counter == 3 … break` are unidiomatic in Ruby.  Here, I would recommend a `for` loop.

Note that you print `Next question` for the last question, which I consider inappropriate, but I have preserved the behaviour below.

```
questions = [
    "What is the command for a 'for' loop?",
    "What is another name for a method?",
    "what are the three types of loops that I know of?",
]
answers = [
    "for",
    "function",
    "while, for, and until",
]

for question, answer in questions.zip(answers)
  puts question
  answer_attempt = gets.chomp.downcase
  if answer_attempt == answer
    puts "Good job. Next question.."
  else
    puts "Incorrect. Next question"
  end
end
puts "all done"
```

Data that are logically related should be stored together.  The simple quick fix, applied above, is to `zip` the questions and answers, which has the same effect as writing an *n* × 2 array:

```
qa = [
  ["What is the command for a 'for' loop?", "for"],
  ["What is another name for a method?", "function"],
  ["what are the three types of loops that I know of?", "while, for, and until"],
]

for question, answer in qa
  …
end
```

Or, consider writing a `Hash` instead:

```
qa = Hash[
  "What is the command for a 'for' loop?", "for",
  "What is another name for a method?", "function",
  "what are the three types of loops that I know of?", "while, for, and until",
]
```

Any of these solutions would facilitate randomizing the order of the questions, should you decide to take that next step.

---

Note that the most basic kind of loop in Ruby is introduced simply with the `loop` keyword.